# Symetry of circular distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Good day,

i wanted to ask somebody for an oppinion about one thing i found in the statistical book (Mardia, Jupp - Directional statistic).

They were defining circular symmetric distribution in following sense:

the distribution of circular random variable $\theta$ is symmetrical about the $\mu,$ if the distribution is invariant under the transformation

$$\theta \rightarrow \mu-\theta.$$
And if the $\theta$ is symmetrical about $\mu$ and has density $f(\theta),$ then 
$$f(\theta-\mu)=f(\mu-\theta).$$

So my point is, is the transformation right? Based on my knowledge from linear case i would say it should be $\theta \rightarrow 2\mu-\theta.$
And the second question is, i believe that both the transformation and the equality between densities, should be with respect to$\mod 2\pi.$
And of course, i am not sure about the equality up there, if there should not be something like $f(\mu-\theta)=f(\mu+\theta)$?

Thanks, for any comments.
Have good day.

Comment: Yes, symmetry about $\mu$ is invariance by the transformation $\theta\to2\mu-\theta$, not $\theta\to\mu-\theta$. A typo in your book, nothing extraordinary, better to move on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and what would you say about my other questions?

Comment: That once one understands that the relevant symmetry is $\theta\to2\mu-\theta$, there is not much to add.